# FxCop - TFS integration : Need to create TFS bug to the last checked in person if FxCop fails

Tags: fxcop, tfsintegrationplatform

We are in a specific requirement regarding FxCop integration with TFS2010. The requirement is as follows.
- Execute the build.in specific intervals (There is already a method)
- Run the FxCop after each build. (This is too simple and known)
- If anything fails,need to create a TFS bug item and assign to the person who checked in the file last time.

We know that 'gated checkin' the the best way. But due to some reasons we cannot adopt that. The challenge we are facing is on the creation of the bugs against the last checked in person of each file.

Does anybody have done this type of solution before? Are there any code available public which does this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The case about last person who changed each file seems quite specific, doubtfull there will be such implementation in public, more common case as you mention is CI build with Gated checkin, other option would be to deploy a checkin policy to run the FxCop before checkins.

The solution is not very difficult using api - you need an build activity that takes the list of FxCop errors (or just error files) and locates the item and gets its last checkin from source controls history, and creates bug for submitter.

Comment: Thanks drk. We started development using TFS sdk. We were searching for any publicly available similar solution/code so that we can avoid coding :-) .

Comment: The only project i can suggest is the http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/ but I doubt they will have exactly the case, still this can be a good example and/or guideline for your own efforts.

Comment: Which part(s) of this do you not know how to do: fail the build if FxCop fails, create a work item if the build fails, and/or assign the work item to the user who last checked in?

Comment: Thanks Nicole for spending time for me. As I said in my previous comment "We were searching for any public similar solution so that we can avoid coding" .There is no part in this whole process which technically challenging. Programmers are becoming little lazy now a days :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was completed by coding the whole part. The basic idea is as follows

1. Take latest and run the exsting build script () which produce pdb as well
2. At the end of the build script start FxCops using FxCopCmd and get the output to xml file
3. Parse the xml and find out the xml message nodes which contains failed reviews
4. Extract the code file path from the above xml node
5. Map the file path to TFS path (ie c:\code to tfs path starting with $\code)
6. Find the last checked in person's details
7. Create and assign a bug to that person.

This was specific to our project where we cannot implement the gated checkin due to the large code base and high frequency code check ins. But had to implement automated reviews.

This can be closed